# DocuSign signing language always english

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

We have an integration with DocuSign and sending out documents to recipients in different languages by e-mail.

The language of the e-mail is set correctly through the API, using the `EmailNotification` property of the recipient. We have only 1 recipient for each of these documents.

```cs
EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification
{
    SupportedLanguage = "es",
}
```

When the recipient clicks on the link in the e-mail they received, the signing session is opened, but the language of the session is always English. We would like to set the language of the signing session to the same language the e-mail was received in.

I am aware that the language of the signing session can be changed by the user, in which case it is saved and from then on the next sessions would be opened in the language they have selected. This is not our concern, the only goal is to make the language the correct one for the first signing. If the user changes the language after that on the client side, we do not care.

The e-mail address to which we are sending the e-mail is not registered in DocuSign, has no DocuSign account.

What we have tried:

- Set the regional settings of the sender to some other language
- Use custom Brand sending resource file to set the labels on the signing session
- Use Incognito mode to open the signing session
- Use a Guest profile in Google Chrome to open the signing session
- Create a brand new e-mail address to make sure it has not been used to sign any documents before

None of the above worked. The only way we were able to change the language of the signing is by changing the browser language.
Even if we use a custom Brand resource file, the session will be loaded in english. We can see the changes made to the resource file, so it's getting it from the right place, but it's getting the English labels.

According to DocuSign, if a recipient does not have a DocuSign account, and has no cookies saved, the `SupportedLanguage` property should take effect, but it does not seem to be working like that in our case.

Is there some other way we could try and make this work?

Checking the requests sent when the signing session is opened, we found that the request to  `https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/envelope?ti=[id]` gives back the following json structure:
[image]
It only sends an ID, so from that point on we are not sure what the logic on the other side uses to determine the language of the session.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the following link:

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-recipient-email-languages

Please review and check